# GitHub showing full file as modified

Tags: git, github, diff

I have just modified a single line on a file on a git repository hosted at GitHub I forked. When I push the commit to GitHub the web UI shows the full file as modified. I did nothing special for changing the file treatment to binary or something like that, and I have done this kind of things a thousand times. My local git client shows just one line finished but it seems GitHub considers this as a whole file change. Why?

https://github.com/axelcostaspena/cordova-wifiinfo-plugin/commit/cc24879cf223a47ab4db26cfc4d186f87c93cc17

Comment: End-of-line change, I'm sure. Do you have file `.gitattributes`?

Comment: @phdthat was the silly questio I was needing! Thank you :) Please post as answer

Comment: man... this is a _thousandicate_.

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena I don't see an answer in my question. :-) Did you push `.gitattributes`? Or changed `core.crlf` config?

Comment: @phd added a gitattributes forcing the java extension to use crlf on the repo, since i am not the maintainer and am not allowed to normalize line endings across project but need just to keep them untouched as I work on my pull request